# How to debug webapps

Tags: unity, 12.10, webapps

I'd like to create a webapp to integrate with a music website and include the played songs in the Sound Menu.

I'm looking at the code for the Grooveshark and Pandora scripts as an example that is helping me get started.

However, I do not quite grasp what's happening behind the scenes and I'd like to debug my script to see how it works.

What's the best way to debug webapps?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty broad.

The Network pane in Chrome's web inspector is quite handy. You might also find `httpflow` useful for seeing what goes over the wire.